# Unable To Download Google API Credentials

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api, google-api-ruby-client

I have set up my app on Googles Developer Console, activated the Google Calendar API, created a Client ID, I just cannot download the client_secrets.json. Is there any way that I can get the download to work?

Comment: How are you trying to download the credentials? Are you getting any error while downloading? please explain it clearly.

Comment: I am clicking the 'download JSON' button and no, nothing happens after i click the button @SGC

Comment: I created the project in developers console,enabled the API's required. Then when I go to API's&Auth->Credentials, I see an arrow to download the JSON. When I click on this arrow, json was downloaded.

Comment: Just tried it again, no dice. Maybe I am missing something? @SGC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Chrome?  If not, try that.  I had the same issue in IE and switching to Chrome allowed me to download the json without issue.

Comment: I am using Safari, but I will try!

Answer (score 1):

I also tried that with chrome. The download button doesn't seems to be working. However managed to download it with the download button on the home screen download button which is situated in right corner of your OAuth 2.0 Client IDs

Answer (score 0):

I looked for it few hours
where to download credentials file

[button_configure_a_project][1]

will give you credentials.json
find a button "configure project and enjoy))
"
[1]: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating?authuser=1#get_your_backend_servers_oauth_20_client_id